# Loading from mysqldump with PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a mysqldump of the format:

```
INSERT INTO `MY_TABLE` VALUES (893024968,'342903068923468','o03gj8ip234qgj9u23q59u','testing123','HTTP','1','4213883b49b74d3eb9bd57b7','blahblash','2011-04-19 00:00:00','448','206',NULL,'GG');
```

How do I load this data using pig? I have tried;

```
A = LOAD 'pig-test/test.log' USING PigStorage(',') AS (ID: chararray, USER_ID: chararray, TOKEN: chararray, NODE: chararray, CHANNEL: chararray, CODE: float, KEY: chararray, AGENT: chararray, TIME: chararray, DURATION: float, RESPONSE: chararray, MESSAGE: chararray, TARGET: chararray);
```

Using , as a delimiter works fine, but I want the ID to be an int and I cannot figure out how to chop off the leading "INSERT INTO `MY_TABLE` VALUES (" and the trailing ");" when loading.

Also how should I load datetime information so that I can query it?

Any help you can give would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You could load each record as a line of text and then try to regex/extract the field with [MyRegExLoader](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pig/trunk/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MyRegExLoader.java?view=markup) or [REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html#REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL):

```
A = LOAD 'data' AS (record: CHARARRAY);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(record, 'INSERT INTO...., \'(\d+)\', ...');
```

It is a kind of a hack but you can use [REPLACE](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html#REPLACE) for chopping off the extra text too:

```
B = FOREACH A
    GENERATE
      (INT) REPLACE(ID, 'INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (', ''),
      ...
      REPLACE(TARGET, ');', '');
```

Currently there is a problem with semicolon so you might need to do your own [REPLACE](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pig/trunk/src/org/apache/pig/builtin/REPLACE.java?view=markup).

There is not native [date type](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-1314) in Pig but you can jungle with the date utils in [PiggyBank](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pig/trunk/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/evaluation/datetime/convert/) or build your own UDF in order to convert it to a Unix long.

Another way would also be doing a **simple script** (Python...) for preparing the data for loading.